# What is the Syntax for Refetching a Query after a Local State Change in React

Tags: reactjs, graphql, fetch, apollo

I am relatively new to Apollo and GraphQL, and I need to make a requery after several mutations, since the recoil states don't want to update in time and a million errors get thrown off after some of the mutations. I simply put do not know how to do this and have been unable to find any relevant documentation to my scenario.
The following code is inside of the`App.js` file.

```
// Mutations
  const { loading: loadingO, error: errorO, data: dataO, refetch: refetchO } = useQuery(GET_OWNER)
  const { loading: loadingM, error: errorM, data: dataM, refetch: refetchM } = useQuery(GET_MANAGER)

  const handleRefresh = () => {
    setRefresh(!refresh)
    if (role && id){
      if (role == "MANAGER"){
        // reftechM
      }
      if (role == "OWNER"){
        // refetchO
      }
    }
  }

  useEffect( () => {
    console.log("???")
  }, [refetchM, refetchO])
```

...where `handleRefresh` is essentially called after every mutation, or of course, every refresh. However, just calling `refetch` does not work, and I have been very unable to find the proper syntax for my issue. Does anyone know the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the useQuery hook checks the Apollo Client cache to see if all the data you requested is already available locally. If all data is available locally, useQuery returns that data and doesn't query your GraphQL server. This cache-first policy is Apollo Client's default fetch policy. If you say that you will call handleRefresh() after mutation the below code will work fine.

[here read fetch policy](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#setting-a-fetch-policy)

```
  const { loading: loadingO, error: errorO, data: dataO, refetch: refetchO } = useQuery(GET_OWNER, {
  fetchPolicy: "network-only",
})
  const { loading: loadingM, error: errorM, data: dataM, refetch: refetchM } = useQuery(GET_MANAGER, {
  fetchPolicy: "network-only",
})

  const handleRefresh = () => {
    setRefresh(!refresh)
    if (role && id){
      if (role == "MANAGER"){
        refetchM()
      }
      if (role == "OWNER"){
        refetchO()
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this directly from apollo docs:

> Refetching queries after a mutation
>
> In certain cases, writing an update function to update the cache after
> a mutation can be complex, or even impossible if the mutation doesn't
> return modified fields.
>
> In these cases, you can provide a refetchQueries option to the
> useMutation hook to automatically rerun certain queries after the
> mutation completes.
>
> For details, see Refetching queries.
>
> Note that although refetchQueries can be faster to implement than an
> update function, it also requires additional network requests that are
> usually undesirable. For more information, see this blog post."

Source: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/advanced-topics/